# Grails will not load in tomcat - JDBC issue

Tags: tomcat, grails, jdbc

Getting the following in grails when it tries to load in tomcat(war deployment) - This is happening after an upgrade to grails 2.1.2 from grails 1.3.7

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.inet.tds.ag.getJDBCMajorVersion()I
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:126)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:712)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:153)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:170)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:121)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:104)
  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.inet.tds.ag.getJDBCMajorVersion()I
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:126)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.initialize(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:74)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:52)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1443)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
  ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.inet.tds.ag.getJDBCMajorVersion()I
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:126)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
  ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.inet.tds.ag.getJDBCMajorVersion()I
  at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingDatabaseMetaData.getJDBCMajorVersion(DelegatingDatabaseMetaData.java:338)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.JdbcSupportLoader.useContextualLobCreation(JdbcSupportLoader.java:78)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.JdbcSupportLoader.loadJdbcSupport(JdbcSupportLoader.java:52)
  at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:118)
  at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863)
  at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859)
  at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsAnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(GrailsAnnotationConfiguration.java:133)
  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean.java:155)
  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean.java:146)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
  ... 51 more
```

I find the jar in my WEB-INF/lib directory after tomcat explodes the war so I don't think it's a dependency issue.

Comment: Can you paste BuildConfig.groovy into your question?

Comment: interestingly enough the problem went away when I switched to a different jdbc driver, I'm guessing it's an issue with the driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the cause is the version of your JDBC.
which database do you use and which version for the database & JDBC ?

Comment: it was indeed an issue with the database driver version thanks